# SSRS Subscription strategies

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm hoping someone with a little more experience than me will know a better way to schedule SSRS reports.

Here is my situation: I have a report on my SSRS report server which takes about a minute to run.  I have about a dozen subscriptions setup on the report which cause it output into an excel file on a network drive every hour.  About a dozen users check this file regularly, as it contains an queue of work that's come in from their helpdesk.

I believe the users are leaving the file open in Excel, because periodically the files starts locking and I get these errors:

> Failure writing file  : The process cannot access the file
>   '' because it is being used by another process.

Even though I've told them all to make copies of the file and only open it locally, they still are having trouble with this.

It seems like a natural way to use SSRS, but because of human tendencies, it is not really working.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try using `@timestamp` variable in the filename to avoid subscription overwrites the same file the end user has open? If you did not, let me know I'll post an answer. Also you can google it.

Comment: Have you already considered emailing the list to them?

Comment: Both of these options make a little more difficult for the users to get at the data because they create multiple versions of the file.  The users will have to make sure they are looking at the latest file or latest email.  However, that may be what I have to do.